# Recording RGB video with PyOpenNI

Tags: python, video, openni

I have installed PyOpenNI on my computer, and I want to record RGB videos with my camera.

On this link, https://github.com/jmendeth/PyOpenNI/blob/master/examples/record.py, it shows how to record depth video.

But I don't need depth video. I need image video. And I couldn't find any API tutorial for that.

How can I record an image video with this damn OpenNI?

Thanks,

Comment: Wild guess: use `ImageGenerator` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only RGB video, why are you going for pyopenni or openni?  Even if you haven't installed openni drivers,  the computer treats a kinect as a standard usb camera. I tried that after a fresh install of opencv and it worked.  The code contained a image display program for standard usb camera.

Comment: Any standard one . For example in opencv Python follow this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)